# What does an image look like as a Blob?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blob

I am working on an AppEngine application, to store images, they have to be stored in a `BlobProperty`.
Is there a Mac/Linux way to convert images to their Blob representation or is there any tool (especially online) that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blobs do store bytes, and images ( as any other file ) are represented by bytes, so you just store it

See: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Blob

Answer (score 2):

"Blob" stands for "Binary Large OBject". It's bytes. Just instantiate a `db.Blob`, passing the bytes.